# how to display the button inside the input in lightning

Tags: lightning-aura-components, button, inputtext

i am trying to achieve this, placing the search button inside the input. Onclick of search icon, i need to invoke other functions. How to make the search icon acting as button and invoke the js function once its clicked? Added the code below in the comment so far written

[image]

Comment: <div class="slds-form-element">
    <div class="slds-form-element__control">
         <div class="slds-input-has-icon slds-input-has-icon--right">
             <img class="slds-input__icon searchIcon" aria-hidden="true" src="{!$Resource.SearchIcon}"/>
                <ui:inputText value="{!v.SearchTerm}" class="slds-input search-input" placeholder="Search by Account Name" />
         </div>
   </div>
</div>

Answer (score 1):

The Base Component `lightning:input` has a search attribute, which when defined as type = "search" will display the Lightning Design System search utility icon. You can invoke the search function when user hits the 'enter' key.

*As per Salesforce documentation.*

An input field for entering a search string. This field displays the Lightning Design System search utility icon.

```
<lightning:input type="search" label="Search" name="search" />
```

To indicate activity in the search field with a spinner, such as data loading, use the isLoading attribute.

```
<lightning:input type="search" label="Search" isLoading="true" />
```

If you want to build your own custom Component using Lightning Design System, please refer to the below blog posts.

[Create Re-Usable Custom Lookup In Salesforce Lightning Component Version 2 : Dynamic](http://sfdcmonkey.com/2017/07/17/re-usable-custom-lookup/)

[Lookup component in Salesforce Lightning](http://www.jitendrazaa.com/blog/salesforce/lookup-component-in-salesforce-lightning/)

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are looking for something like this.

```
<div class="slds-form-element">
        <label class="slds-form-element__label" for="text-input-id-1">Search</label>
        <div class="slds-form-element__control slds-input-has-icon slds-input-has-icon_right" onclick="{!c.clickme}">
            <lightning-icon size="x-small" class="slds-icon slds-input__icon slds-input__icon_right slds-icon-text-default" icon-name="utility:search"></lightning-icon>
            <input type="text" class="slds-input" />
        </div>
    </div>
```